# How can I access to the marker popup text in a map in JS or JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet

I'm using a Leafletjs map with multiple marker bind to a popup text.
How can I access to the popup text on click ?
The both function doesn't work:

```
    $('.mapLink').on('click', function(){
    var userName = $(this).text();
    console.log(userName);
    });


  $(".mapLink").click(function () { 
    var userName = $(this).text();
    console.log(userName);
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle link if possible ?

Comment: Need to see more code and the HTML. And what does 'doesn't work' mean? Does the click event never get triggered, or is the data not what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, this is my code:

```
              L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: 'key'
            }).addTo(mymap);
```

and this is my JQ code:

```
                    //Set new markers
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        var marker = L.marker([value.Lng, value.Lat], .addTo(mymap);
                        var nameLink = '<a class="nav-link mapLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#composeModal">Envoyer un message à ' + value.name + '</a>'
                        marker.bindPopup(nameLink);
                        markerList.push(marker);
                        marker.addTo(markersLayer);
                        console.log(markerList);
                    });
```

I'm using a loop to add marker from a json. I would like to get the value of 'value.name'to pass to the form in hyperlink popup.
Thanks